# For a strictly convex function $f:\mathbb{R}^n\to \mathbb{R}$ critical point is unique.

Tags: real-analysis, convex-analysis, hessian-matrix

Definition. A smooth function $f:\mathbb{R}^n\to \mathbb{R} $ is strictly convex

if its Hessian matrix $[\frac{\partial^2f}{\partial x^i \partial x^j}] $ as a quadratic form is strictly positive definite.

I want to show that if f has a critical point then the critical point is unique. 
I would appreciate any help. Thank you.

Comment: Not really my field, but I'd say assume there are two and then restrict $f$ to the line connecting the two critical points.  By positive definiteness, you should get that the restriction has an everywhere non-zero second derivative, which would be a contradiction.

Comment: What do you mean by a critical point? Zero derivative?

Comment: The definition is wrong, according to yours, $x^4$ is not strictly convex?

Comment: @copper.hat Yes

Comment: @Callus Thanks then use M.V.T?

Comment: @max_zorn It's from Ana da silva's book lectures on symplectic geometry.. I actually don't know any terminology from convex analysis.

Comment: That's what I was thinking, but @max_zorn raises a legit point, and shows why I shouldn't comment on subjects I don't know very well.

Comment: @Metamorphosis: I recommend you check out Boyd and Vandenberghe's *Convex Optimization* book, which is available online for free. Chapter 3 has what you need.

Comment: @max_zorn Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3):

It is straightforward to verify that a differentiable convex function 
on $\mathbb{R}^n$ satisfies
$f(x+h) -f(x) \ge {\partial f(x) \over \partial x} h$ for all $h$.

In particular, $x$ is a global $\min$ of $f$ **iff** ${\partial f(x) \over \partial x} = 0$.

Suppose $x,x'$ are two critical points, then ${\partial f(x) \over \partial x} = {\partial f(x') \over \partial x} = 0$ and
so $x,x'$ are global $\min$.

Since $f$ is convex, every point along $[x,x']$ is also a global $\min$ and hence ${\partial f(y) \over \partial x} = 0$ for all
$y \in [x,x']$.

By considering the 2nd order Taylor expansion of $\phi(t) = f(x+ t(x'-x))$ we see that
$\phi(1) -\phi(0) = 0 = {1 \over 2}\langle x'-x, {\partial^2 f(x+\xi(x'-x)) \over \partial x^2} (x'-x) \rangle $, which 
contradicts the positive definiteness of the Hessian.

**Note**: If the function is strictly convex, then the Hessian argument
is unnecessary. If $f(x)=f(y)$ and $x \neq y$ then
$f({x+y \over 2}) < f(x)$. Hence there cannot be two distinct minimisers and hence there cannot be two distinct critical points.